# Apple cider vinegar and Blue Mold

Tags: vinegar, apples

I'm a week into making apple cider vinegar. I've used jars and the apples at the top were not covered with liquid. A blue mold formed. I've removed it. Should I carry on or should I start again? If I carry on would the final resulting vinegar be OK for consumption? Or just topical application? Any advise greatly appreciated. Hate to Waste!